# How to get selected row data in NSTableView where multiple selection is allowed?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I have got a NSTableView where multiple selection is allowed. Now when the user selects multiple rows and click on a Button, I need to fetch all the selected row values. Please help!

For fetching a single row data I am using the code as below

```
    var row = tableViewOutlet.selectedRow
    var column = tableViewOutlet.tableColumnWithIdentifier("EmpName")
    var cell: AnyObject? = column?.dataCellForRow(row)
    println("Cell Value - \(cell!.stringValue)")
```

But I want it for multiple rows in a loop

I wrote the code as below

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableViewOutlet.numberOfSelectedRows; ++i) {

            if(tableViewOutlet.isRowSelected(i))
            {
                var row = tableViewOutlet.selectedRow
                var column = tableViewOutlet.tableColumnWithIdentifier("EmpName")
                var cell: AnyObject? = column?.dataCellForRow(row)
                println("Selected Emp Name - \(cell!.stringValue)")
            }
       }
```

But it is giving me only last selected row value. Tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

There is an API misunderstanding:

`numberOfSelectedRows` returns how many rows are selected.

Use `selectedRowIndexes` which returns an `NSIndexSet` instance containing the indexes of the selected rows

You can enumerate the index set with

Swift 1.2

```
for (_, index) in enumerate(tableViewOutlet.selectedRowIndexes)
{

}
```

Swift 2

```
for (_, index) in tableViewOutlet.selectedRowIndexes.enumerate() {}
```

Swift 3+

```
for (_, index) in tableViewOutlet.selectedRowIndexes.enumerated() {}
```

But I'd retrieve the data from the table view data source rather than from the table cell

Comment: This code works in Swift 3 with only one change:  `for (_, index) in nearTableView.selectedRowIndexes.enumerated()`  I do not understand the syntax, however, of: `for (_, index)`  I am grateful for the code, but can someone please explain the underscore?

Comment: @CraigSmith `enumerate` is a generic function of all collection types which conforms to `SequenceType`. It returns a `SequenceType` containing pairs `(element, index)` and the element is just not used in `NSIndexSet`. The underscore represents *don't care*.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you, Stefan.

Comment: @vadian I think `enumerate` on `SequenceType` will return `(index, element)` (the actual element is the second one). The `index` is not the row number, the `element` contains the row number. More like `(i, rowIndexElement)`, where `i` is just the position of the row number in the `selectedRowIndexes`. Why not just use `forEach`? `tableViewOutlet.selectedRowIndexes.forEach { (row: Int) in  print("Row: \(row)")  }`